# Accessing attributes of an AngularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the directive

```
(function () {

/**
 * Config
 */
var moduleName = 'eBayPartsFinder.directives.searchFilters';

/**
 * Module
 */
angular.module(moduleName, []).directive('searchFilters', searchFiltersDirective);

function searchFiltersDirective($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            disabled: '=',
            onChange: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/lib/EbayPartsFinder/SearchFilters.html',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('invalid', true);
            
        }
    };
}})();
```

Then in another html file I have

```
 <search-filters id="BatchResultFilters" name="searchFilters" model="FiltersStaging.GlobalFilters" disabled="Searching"></search-filters>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="ApplyFilters()" ng-disabled="searchFilters.invalid" tabindex="15">Apply Filter</button>
```

So I'm trying to access the invalid attribute of the searchFilters directive in its parent where I have  ng-disabled="searchFilters.invalid"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct approach. You want to use `ng-disabled` on a  $scope object parameter, not an html element attribute. If that directive is used in many pages, consider using $emit in the directive and catch that in the containing controller with $on - that can set the parameter on or off and so affect your `ng-disabled`. There are other ways of architecting this to make it more plug and play across different pages but I'm not sure if that's your goal.

```
function searchFiltersDirective($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '=',
      disabled: '=',
      onChange: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/lib/EbayPartsFinder/SearchFilters.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('invalid', true);
      scope.emit("invalid_set", true)

    }
  };

  // controller

  $scope.$on('invalid_set', function(evt, data) {
    $scope.searchFilters.invalid = data;
  });
```

[Read more about $broadcast, $emit and $on](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx) - very useful in AngularJS